# Treat a literal variable as a constant with Ryacas (or an alternative)

Tags: r, symbolic-math, yacas

With **Ryacas**, one has:

```
> yac_str("Simplify(2*x^2*4 + x^2*5)")
[1] "13*x^2"
```

Now, instead of `4` and `5`, I would like to give two letters treated as constants. That is, **Ryacas** does:

```
> yac_str("Simplify(2*x^2*a + x^2*b)")
[1] "2*x^2*a+x^2*b"
```

but I would like that it treats `x` as an unknown variable and `a` and `b` as constants, i.e. I would like to get the result:

```
(2*a+b)*x^2
```

I spent one hour to try with no luck. Is it possible? Otherwise, with another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way with **caracas**.

```r
library(caracas)

def_sym(x, y, z, a, b)

as.character(sympy_func(x^2 + a*x^2 + 2*y + b*y + x*z + a*x*z, "Poly", domain = "RR[a,b]"))
# "Poly((1.0*a + 1.0)*x^2 + (1.0*a + 1.0)*x*z + (1.0*b + 2.0)*y, x, y, z, domain='RR[a,b]')"
```

You can also work with rational numbers:

```r
poly <- 
  sympy_func(x^2 + a*x^2 + 2/3*y + b*y + x*z + a*x*z, "Poly", domain = "QQ[a,b]")
as.character(poly)
# "Poly((a + 1)*x^2 + (a + 1)*x*z + (b + 2/3)*y, x, y, z, domain='QQ[a,b]')"
```

To get the coefficient of a term, e.g. `xz` (i.e. `x^1y^0z^1`):

```r
sympy <- get_sympy()
sympy$Poly$nth(poly$pyobj, 1, 0, 1)
# a + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be just how yacas wants to simplify that expression. SymPy does it the way you want though, and it has an R wrapper called `caracas`

```r
library(caracas)

a <- as_sym("a")
b <- as_sym("b")
x <- as_sym("x")

caracas::simplify(2*x^2*a+x^2*b)
#> [caracas]:  2        
#>            x *(2*a + b)
```

I don't like the way it prints `x^2`, but you can't have everything.

Comment: Thanks. That is strange. There's nothing to distinguish variables from constants. I'm not sure this will give the expected output with the large expression I have. Indeed, the **x^2** is horrible.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent but that's how you would simplify it if a and b were variables anyway.

Comment: Yes, but my real expression is much more complicated. I've just took a look at the doc, there's a **symbol** function with an ellipsis argument, perhaps we can set **constant=TRUE** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665207/define-a-variable-in-sympy-to-be-a-constant). I gonna try.

Comment: I successfully installed **caracas**. One can do **as.character** to get **x^2**.

Comment: How did it work out with your larger expressions @StéphaneLaurent? I haven't used SymPy before, but have used yacas before and it always felt a bit limited.

Comment: So far it didn't work as I expected. I get **a^12*z^12 + 6.0*a^10*b^2*z^12** while I declared **a** and **b** as constant symbols, so I expected **(a^12+ 6.0*a^10*b^2)*z^12**. But I'm still working on it. Also it replaces the fractions with their decimal approximations.